# On infinite global dimensions of "slightly non-commutative" rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, homological-dimension, projective-resolution

Assume $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring of finite Krull dimension; $R'$ is a not commutative ring that contains $R$ in its center and also finitely generated as an $R$-module.

If the (left) global dimension of $R'$ is infinite, should there exist a finitely generated $R'$-module whose projective dimension is infinite? Is this clear if $R$ is regular?

Comment: Related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207223/different-ways-of-having-infinite-global-dimension

Comment: Also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421776/ring-of-infinite-global-dimension-which-does-not-have-a-finitely-generated-modul